$\int_{\mathbb R^3}e^{{-\tau\lvert x\rvert}^2}{\lvert x\rvert}^Kdx_1dx_2dx_3$ and its higher dimensional analogues
Problem: Let $\lvert x\rvert=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$. When $n=3$, determine the value of the (Riemann-)integral $$\int_{\mathbb R^3}e^{{-\tau\lvert x\rvert}^2}{\lvert x\rvert}^Kdx_1dx_2dx_3,$$ where $\tau>0$ and $K\in \mathbb N$. When $n\in \mathbb N$, argue why $$\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{{-\tau\lvert x\rvert}^2}{\lvert x\rvert}^Kdx_1\ldots dx_n=C\tau^{-(n+K)/2}$$ for some $C>0$ that does not depend on $\tau$.
So far: I tried changing to spherical coordinates, but the answer becomes very complicated, so I'm afraid I've done something wrong here. So far in this course we have not covered any special functions and the integrals have been relatively well-behaved, which leads me to believe there's some trick here that I'm missing, which would then simplify the problem. After changing to spherical coordinates I get $$\int_{\mathbb R^3}e^{{-\tau\lvert x\rvert}^2}{\lvert x\rvert}^Kdx_1dx_2dx_3=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\tau r^2}r^K\cdot r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\varphi=4\pi\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\tau r^2}r^{K+2}dr,$$ but this is where I get completely stuck.
Edit: Setting $u=\tau r^2$ leads to the answer $$4\pi\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\tau r^2}r^{K+2}dr=2\pi\tau^{-(3+K)/2}\int_0^\infty e^{-u}u^{(K+1)/2}du=2\pi\tau^{-(3+K)/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{K+3}{2}\right),$$ which is of the desired form, but I am unsure of how to generalize this to $\mathbb R^n$.

Spherical coordinates should work. Where were you stuck?

Edited to specify where I get stuck.

great! Now rescale $\tau r^2 \rightarrow y^2$

$\displaystyle r = \left(t /\tau\right)^{1/2}$ leads to a $\displaystyle\tt Gamma$ function.

As you wrote yourself, in spherical coordinates one gets
$$\int_{\mathbb R^3}e^{{-\tau\lvert x\rvert}^2}{\lvert x\rvert}^Kdx_1dx_2dx_3=4\pi\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\tau r^2}r^{K+2}dr.$$
For the last expression, you can use partial integration:
\begin{align}\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-\tau r^2} r^{K+2}d r &= -\frac{1}{2\tau}\int\limits_0^\infty (-2\tau re^{-\tau r^2}) r^{K+1}d r \\
&= -\frac{1}{2\tau}\underbrace{[e^{-\tau r^2}r^{K+1}]_0^\infty}_{=0} +\frac{K+1}{2\tau}\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-\tau r^2}r^Kdr\end{align}
Clearly, this can be repeated as long as $K\geq 2$, and the final result will depend $-$ up to a factor $-$ on whether $K$ is even or odd.
(I think from here you can do it yourself, but feel free to ask again.)
